# Jquery append issue with BulletList C# control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, winforms

```
var eq = Cost/Sales;
var delimiters = "+-*/()";
var result = new Array();
var chunk = "";
var regex =  /[()*/+-]|[A-Z a-z]+|\d+/g;
var parts = eq.match(regex);
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
      $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Destination").append('<li>'+parts[i]+'</li>');
       alert('<li>'+parts[i]+'</li>');     
}
```

---

```
<CTExtension:EmptyBulletedList ID="Destination" runat="Server" class="connectedSortable"></CTExtension:EmptyBulletedList>
```

I have following code in my javascript to break the value in to array. Now I want to append it one by one into destination id-control which is bullet list from my C#. But the above code does not append the values. Please help! and it creates the ul tag when i run the page

Comment: Are you getting the `alert` for each iteration?

Comment: Yes i m getting the values

Comment: Are you sure there's an element on the page with the `id` "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Destination"? Have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: No..no errors and I am sure that I have control with the mentioned id.

Comment: Is ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Destination the id of a `<ul>`? Because it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jTTP7/

Comment: You have `var eq = Cost/Sales;`, so `eq` should result in a number. Then you use `eq.match(regex);`. Except `.match` is only a string's method. So that wouldn't work.

Comment: I have different calculation depending on what user has created and hence i put one example of that.. (Like we create maths calculation)

Comment: Does anything related to c# bulletlist control that I cant append anything ?

Answer (score 0):

At runtime, is the value of your #ctl00 still the same?  That looks like a placeholder in ASP.NET meaning the actual value could change at runtime.   Also, when you say it is not appending the values, what is it doing instead.  Are you getting any javascript errors in the console?  Are you getting the alert?  Do a View Source on the page after it loads and make sure the ID you are passing the JQuery selector is correct.

I would assume the ControlID is changing, and therefore your selector is no longer valid.

See my Fiddle below, it's working, start from a working solution and make changes until it breaks, then you will know where it's going wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/zWXCN/

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                  $("#test").append('<li>'+i+'</li>');
                   //alert('<li>'+i+'</li>');     
            }
```

Comment: I m getting alert and yes no errors in console but its not getting appended in the control.

Comment: See the fiddle above and go from there.

Comment: Please see the control from c# that I m using and in console it shows up in ul tag. I have no idea if something goes wrong there!

Comment: Try using a class name instead.  On your C# control, add a class named "appendList", and change your selector to be $('.appendList') instead.

Comment: I tried and no result... I think its something bad with bulletlist?

Comment: When you view Source (after a page is fully loaded), and locate the control on the page, what are the ID and Class settings for the UL tag?

Comment: <ul id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Destination" class="connectedSortable">

</ul> it shows me this in console

Comment: In that case, try  $(".connectedSortable").append('<li>test</li>'); just to see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Directly referencing your element via the automatically generated ASP.NET ID can cause problems.  Can you check if that ID is still correct (using developer tools in the browser)?

Instead you should reference your control like:

`$('#<%= Destination.ClientID %>')`

This means that regardless of the structure of your page, or the implementation of the ClientID, you will always be referencing the correct control.

Comment: If you could update your question with the code you tried with ClientID that would be helpful.

Comment: seems does not works with custom control "CTExtension" ^^ No prop "ClientID" implemented...

Comment: @pouki06 - Surely since the control should (will be?) inheriting from `WebControl` ClientID will be available.